# Not able to send email in iOS

Tags: ios, email

I am trying to send mail in iOS but it doesn't work.

Below is the code, using to send mail.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailCtrl = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mailCtrl.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailCtrl setSubject:@"Definition from CDE iPhone App"];

    NSString *body = [self flattenHTML:[mydef renderHTML:NO landscape:NO]];

    [mailCtrl setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];              
    [self presentModalViewController:mailCtrl animated:YES];
    //[mailCtrl navigationBar].tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [mailCtrl navigationBar].tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [mailCtrl release];
```

above code sets the html code in the body. everything it sets properly but when tapped on the send it doesn't send the mail to the emailid provided ion To box.

Please help....

Comment: R u checking in Simulator or real device?

Comment: In stimulater, It is not possible to send mail with iOS8 and above iOS.

Comment: there is no other way test it on simulator?

Comment: Sorry, but no, There is no other way to send mail with  MFMailComposeViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS simulator doesn't allow you to send email. You'll need a physical device to test this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing the mail view appear ? If so, you need to add the mail delegate method in order to dismiss the view. Add the following to your application:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: What does it do ? The view closes but you never receive the email? You can't send email from the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

`MFMailComposeViewController` Doesn't work in simulator.

In versions PREVIOUS to iOS8, you cannot open `MFMailComposeViewController` in simulator but after iOS8+ versions you can open but you cannot sent mail by simulator. You have to actually use a device.

Comment: No, no way to test in a simulator